# операции с double

Tags: c#, double

результат расчетов print.Price — всегда целое число.

---

Первый случай:

```
s[1] "0,008459" string
instrument.PriceStep 5E-07 double
print.Price 16918 int
```

---

Второй случай:

```
s[1] "0,0084585" string
instrument.PriceStep 5E-07 double
print.Price 16918 int
```

---

```
print.Price = (int)Math.Ceiling((double.Parse(s[1]) / instrument.PriceStep));
```

---

В обоих случаях результат — одно и тоже число. А должно быть разное.

Знаю, что это связано с ограничением размера double и периодическими дробями.

Как правильно выполнить такую операцию?

Comment: Для начала, если вы рассчитываете _цену_, вам стоит от `double` перейти к `decimal`.

Comment: А почему должно быть разное? Обоснуйте.

Comment: ну если взять калькулятор и посчитать, то во втором случае ответ получается 16917. И я потаюсь понять, что  я делаю не так...

Comment: а почему decimal ?

Comment: @Петр потому что денежный тип

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что вычисления с типом `double` точны только если вы остаётесь в рамках *двоичных* дробей, а с типом `decimal` — десятичных.

Сравните:

```
var double1 = 0.008459 / 5e-7;       // 16918.0
var double2 = 0.0084585 / 5e-7;      // 16917.000000000004

var decimal1 = 0.008459m / 5e-7m;    // 16918
var decimal2 = 0.0084585m / 5e-7m;   // 16917
```

Почему вычисления с `double` неточны? Потому что `double` записывает значения в *двоичной* системе. Но ни число `0.008459`, ни дробь `1 / 5e-7` не могут быть точно представленными в двоичной системе. Поэтому результат будет *приблизительно* равен ожидаемому вами числу.

Чтобы в этом убедиться, имеет смысл воспользоваться *точным* строковым представлением двоичного числа (например, [вот этим](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs)):

```
DoubleConverter.ToExactString(0.008459);
    // выдаёт "0.00845899999999999950561768713441779254935681819915771484375"
DoubleConverter.ToExactString(5e-7);
    // выдаёт "0.0000004999999999999999773740559129431293428069693618454039096832275390625"
DoubleConverter.ToExactString(0.008459 / 5e-7);
    // выдаёт "16918"

DoubleConverter.ToExactString(0.0084585);
    // выдаёт "0.008458500000000000740296712820054381154477596282958984375"
DoubleConverter.ToExactString(0.0084585 / 5e-7);
    // выдаёт "16917.00000000000363797880709171295166015625"
```

(Всегда полезно знать, что же под капотом *на самом деле*.)

А вот для `decimal` значения внутри в точности соответствуют тем десятичным дробям, которые вы вводите.

Answer (score 6):

Для денежных значений надо использовать DECIMAL:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/364x0z75.aspx

> Ключевое слово decimal обозначает 128-битный тип данных. По сравнению
>   с типами данных с плавающей запятой, диапазон значений типа decimal
>   меньше, а точность выше, благодаря чему этот тип подходит для
>   финансовых расчетов.

Comment: верно. но они говорят про количество денег а не про цену.

Comment: цена - это сколько денег стоит что-то, это денежная величина